# Thread 1:EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0) en scrollView.delegate = self

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

the thread 1 error for which it gives me a fatal error, the code works but when I get it it does not let me do it gives that error and I don't know how to solve it puestwo that I have no value in the scrollView.delegate = self

import UIKit

class GaleriaBodas: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

```
    @IBOutlet weak var pageControl: UIPageControl!


    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!



override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    scrollView.delegate = self
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

        let anchoPagina : CGFloat = scrollView.frame.width
        let paginaActual : CGFloat = floor(scrollView.contentOffset.x - anchoPagina/2) / anchoPagina + 1
        self.pageControl.currentPage = Int(paginaActual)
    }
}
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is intended for questions asked in English only. https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/07/23/non-english-question-policy/

Comment: `scrollView` is nil I guess?

Comment: If it is null but when I do it through a tutorial, I am new, it went well when I put it in the code of my app I get this error and I do not know how I could solve it

Answer (score 0):

Connect scrollView via Storyboard with your scrollView variable in Code.